# .val() из подгружаемого контента

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Привет всем. Подгрузил контент через jQuery, `.load()` и пытаюсь взять `.val()` по id из контента, не выходит, видимо вне области видимости, помогите разобраться.

Как взять значение `<input>` из подгружаемого блока `.load()` или `.get()`?

Answer (score 1):

Наверное так:

```
$("#result").load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
    alert($("#result input#input_id").val());
});
```

Comment: А уже после load никак?

Comment: Что значит никак?

Так как раз после load, непосредственно после нельзя, т.к. JavaScript однопоточный.

Comment: на вот посмотри game.neatek.ru/auth , сделал отдельную страницу, и пытаюсь выдрать значение 95-102 строка. Причем все это на 1 странице, без load.